# How can I quickly determine the amount of rows in a text file?

Tags: c, text-files

I'm new to using C programming I was wondering if there is a function call that can be used to quickly determine the amount of rows in a text file.

Comment: what's the definition of a row in your text file? is it delimited? fixed size?

Comment: The text file contains a matrix of numbers. I do not know how many rows of numbers there will be

Comment: *If* "matrix" means every line is the same length, you can divide the total size by the length of each line.

Comment: @Jerry that would be clever except I'm guessing he's got an ASCII text file so its unlikely to use the same number of characters per 'matrix element'

Comment: There can be x rows and y columns ..

Comment: where each row goes from left to right..

Comment: don't forget to accept an answer :) welcome to the community!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
int numLines(char *fileName) {
    FILE *f;
    char c;
    int lines = 0;

    f = fopen(fileName, "r");

    if(f == NULL)
        return 0;

    while((c = fgetc(f)) != EOF)
        if(c == '\n')
            lines++;

    fclose(f);

    if(c != '\n')
        lines++;

    return lines;
}
```

Comment: This is an amazing website to get help. Thank you all!

Comment: c is always != '\n', because it's EOF. And c shouldn't be a char. fgetc() returns an int.

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

uint32_t CountRows(FILE* fp, uint8_t line_delimiter){
  uint32_t num_rows = 0;
  uint16_t chr = fgetc(fp);
  while(chr != EOF){
    if(chr == line_delimiter){
      num_rows++;
    }
    chr = fgetc(fp);
  }

  return num_rows;
}
```

Comment: What if the end-of-line character is not '\n' ?

Comment: replace '\n' with your choice of line delimiter :) edited function accordingly

Comment: @Tom: `\n' is *always* the end-of-line character, even on windows, if the file is not opened in binary mode.  The underlying system takes care of making sure of this property.

Answer (score 2):

No. There is a standard Unix utility that does this though, `wc`. You can look up the source code for `wc` to get some pointers, but it'll boil down to simply reading the file from start to end and counting the number of lines/works/whatever.

Answer (score 1):

You have to write your own, *and* you have to be conscious of the formatting of the file... Do lines end with `\n`? or `\r\n`? And what if the last line doesn't end with a newline (as all files should)? You would probably check for these and then count the newlines in the file.

Answer (score 0):

No, theres not. You have to write your own.

If the line-size if fixed, then you could use fseek and ftell to move to the end of the file 
and then calculate it.

If not, you have to go through the file counting lines.

Are you trying to create an array of lines?
Something like

```
char* arr[LINES] //LINES is the amount of lines in the file
```

?

Comment: I figure I would have to loop through the text file and have a counter counting the lines... I just didn't know if there is a easier way..

And yes I have something like char* arr[lines];